# Regrouping values in a bi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How **the good php developer I am not** would solve this problem?

I spent quite some time figuring how to shorten a bi-dimensional array.

```
$expanded = [ [1, 1], [1, 4], [3, 5], [1, 3], [4, 1], [4, 2], [1, 2], [4, 7], [3, 5] ];
```

into :

```
$shortened = [ [1, 10], [4, 10], [3, 10];
```

What I want is, if the first value of two arrays is the same, merge them !

This is what got me the closest to what I want :

```
$expanded = [ [1, 1], [1, 4], [3, 5], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 7], [3, 5] ];

$len = count($expanded);

$shortened[0] = $expanded[0];

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

  for ($j = 1; $j < $len-$i; $j++) {

    if ($expanded[$i][0] == $expanded[$i+$j][0]) {
      $shortened[$i][0] = $expanded[$i][0];
      $shortened[][1] = $shortened[$i][1] + $expanded[$i+$j][1];
    } else {
      $shortened[$i+1] = $expanded[$i+$j];
    }        

  }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belong's to  CodeReview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
$shortened = array_reduce(
    $expanded,
    function (array $carry, array $item) {
        list($one, $two) = $item;
        if (! isset($carry[$one])) {
            $carry[$one] = [ $one, 0 ];
        }
        $carry[$one][1] += $two;
        return $carry;
    },
    []
);
```

Comment: Amazing! I don't have enough reputation to vote up but when I will, I'll come back to vote this up.

Answer (score 0):

I got this far in a few minutes:

```
$expanded = [ [1, 1], [1, 4], [3, 5], [1, 3], [4, 1], [4, 2], [1, 2], [4, 7], [3, 5] ];

foreach ($expanded as $part)
{
  $temp[$part[0]] += $part[1];
}

foreach ($temp as $key => $value)
{
  $shortened[] = [$key, $value];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($shortened);
echo '</pre>';
```

And this is the version I really used, because my PHP < 5.4:

```
$expanded =  array(array(1, 1), 
                   array(1, 4), 
                   array(3, 5), 
                   array(1, 3), 
                   array(4, 1), 
                   array(4, 2), 
                   array(1, 2), 
                   array(4, 7), 
                   array(3, 5));

foreach ($expanded as $part)
{
  $temp[$part[0]] += $part[1];
}

foreach ($temp as $key => $value)
{
  $shortened[] = array($key, $value);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($shortened);
echo '</pre>';
```

The shorted version would look like this:

```
foreach ($expanded as $p) $t[$p[0]]   += $p[1];
foreach ($t as $k => $v)  $shortened[] = [$k,$v];
```